# c# How do I correctly compile code for distribution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compilation, exe

I want to convert my program into something that I can give out and people can use (just to my friends and people I know) but I'm totally lost as of how to do it. I've tried doing lots of things from other forums but none seem to work or actually do what I'm looking for.

I tried using the publishing feature in the build tab but don't like that It makes It into a ClickOnce application as I'd much rather have it as an .exe.

From what I read there is already one of these in the bin\debug folder (I'd use the use the release bin\ folder when I am fully finished) but i don't know how much or what files actually need to be packaged together for it to work on another computer.

My main questions are:

Can I actually make a distributable a application using the bin\debug .exe with all the other files in it?

Do I also need to include the obj and properties folder? (I'm guessing not for the properties but the obj does look kind of important)

Because I've used NuGet packages and references do i have to to include the App.config and packages.config or is this just something that visual studio uses?

sorry if I've got anything wrong with what I've said, I'm way out of my comfort zone here.

Comment: The obj folder is total garbage. Basically everything you want will be in bin/Release. Assuming you have a relatively simple app.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I wouldn't really say its simple but I don't know what sort of complexity someone else would rate it. What would not be in the bin\release folder as an example if i would need to look for other files?

Comment: First thing to know is what kind of application are you building. Is it a web app, a winforms/wpf project?

Comment: @Obmama sometimes you can have resources that aren't copied to that output by default. For example if you add a .jpg file, I don't believe those copy to the output by default, which you would probably want to change to do so, or embed them in the project. That wasn't the best example, but hopefully it makes sense.

Comment: @Steve It's a console app that interacts mainly with the twitter API and a few other websites

Comment: @BrootsWaymb yeah i understand I'll look through it all once and make sure there isn't anything obvious I've left out

Answer (score 3):

For a console application, you should be able to zip up the contents of the `bin/release` directory and distribute it directly.

You can safely exclude `.pdb` files from your archive, though they can help you debug the program if your friends and cohorts encounter errors.

Comment: Alright I'll give it a go and see how it works out. Will it only use files in the zip folder? For instance say there was something that i left out it won't just still work because i have that file some random place on my computer will it?

Comment: Are you referencing any random files on your development machine?  From the way you describe your application, it sounds like you will be good to go with just the `bin/release`.  When you run your application in Release mode, it's running from the `bin/release` dir, so the files it needs ought to be present, unless you have hard-coded file paths somewhere in your code.